# write double variable into binary file in c++

Tags: c++, binary

I am trying to write double variable into a binary file. I am using below code:

```
double x = 1.;    
ofstream mfout;
mfout.open("junk.bin", ios::out | ios::binary  );
mfout.write((char*) &x, sizeof(double));
mfout.close();
```

What it returns to me after converting output binary file to ASCII is this:

.......

The third party software which has to read the file also returns error showing that there is problem. I would be thankful if someone guide me.

Comment: Try viewing the output in a hex editor or some editor that can print the values of each byte (not the ASCII character encodings).

Comment: the output is 00 00 00 CC CC CC CC which is translated to some meaningless characters according to hex convertors

Comment: Why are you casting to a `char*`?  That might change what the function `mfout.write()` does.  It could be that you have some problem with endian-ness.

Comment: This doesn't' address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects to meaningful values instead of default-initializing them and immediately changing them. That is, change `ofstream mfout; mfout.open("junk.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);` to `ofstream mfout("junk.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);`. Also, the call to `mfout.close();` isn't needed. The destructor for `mfout` will close the file.

Comment: There really isn't a question in there. What were you expecting to see if you view a binary value that isn't in ASCII as if it were an ASCII value? (If you write something in Spanish, to an English speaker, it might look like a meaningless bunch of characters. That's should not be surprising.)

Comment: Compiler gives error if I omit casting `(char*)`. What do you suggest?

Comment: Since you're writing a **binary** file, there's no connection between what gets written to the file and any particular set of characters. Binary files usually don't make much sense when treated as text files, and will, indeed, look like "some meaningless characters".

Comment: @TimLudwinski -- the cast is correct. `ofstream::write` takes a first argument of type `const char*`.

Comment: @mohammadalinajafisani -- the cast is correct.

Comment: @mohammadalinajafisani -- the first thing to do is to open the file that you've just written as an input file and see if you can read the data back correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Pete Becker but it didn't worked

Comment: @mohammadalinajafisani *The third party software ...* -- So this other software was written with the same compiler, compiler version, compiler settings, etc.?  If not, good luck having that other piece of software to understand the `double` you've written.

Comment: @PeteBecker -- But when I use `string text = "Hi"; mfout.write(text.c_str(), text.size());`, I see the right output after conversion. Your suggestion to read the file is very good. I'll try it. Thanks

Comment: @mohammadalinajafisani What "conversion" are you talking about exactly? If it's a conversion that doesn't expect a double in binary form, it's not surprising it doesn't work for a double in binary form.

Comment: Yes, when you write text to a binary file you see the text that you wrote. When you write the bytes of a numeric value to a binary file you see the bytes that you wrote, which generally don't represent meaningful characters.

Comment: @PeteBecker what if I convert double to string with something like `sprintf` in MATLAB? something like `to_string`?

Comment: Thanks for everyone contribution, actually the third party software expecting me to input numerical values as strings,as @PeterBecker hinted.

Answer (score 0):

> What it returns to me after converting output binary file to ASCII is this:
>
> .......

No. That's what it returns to you if you interpret it as ASCII without converting it. Since it's not ASCII, interpreting it as ASCII will produce nonsense.

> The third party software which has to read the file also returns error showing that there is problem.

Then it sounds like the third party software isn't expecting a binary file, since that's what you've written.

The file is binary, not ASCII. Only something expecting a single double in binary format (whatever binary format that your platform happens to use with your compiler options and so on) will be able to make sense out of it.